# How can I create custom folder icons in 18.04?

Tags: gnome, icons

With Unity, I was easily able to replace generic folder icons with custom graphics and pictures (especially on my desktop), but the second I upgraded to GNOME-based 17.10 (and now, 18.04), all of my custom icons have reverted back to the generic folder icons.

I've done a fresh installation of 18.04 via Live CD, and I've tried right-clicking **Properties** and then clicking the folder icon to choose an icon, but when I navigate to a folder containing my desired icon and select, nothing changes.

Q: Is there any way to customize folder icons in GNOME? Is there an app that would allow someone to do so? [BTW: Here's what my desktop used to look like in 17.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyc1b.jpg)

Comment: Most probably the second one (upgrade glitch).

Comment: Thanks, Pomsky. Have since done a clean installation of 18.04 via Live CD, but the problem persists. Q: Have you been able to create custom folder icons in 18.04? If so, how did you do it?